# How to load css file in Micronaut using Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf, micronaut

How to load a CSS file in Micronaut using Thymeleaf?

Here is my `index.html` contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link th:href="@{public/style.css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Here is `application.yml`:

```
router:
  static:
    resources:
      default:
        enabled: true
        mapping: /**
        paths: 'classpath:public'
```

Image note:

[image: resource directory structure]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your configuration:

1. As mentioned by Graeme Rocher, `mapping: /**` will bind the public folder to root path of your application i.e file will be available at `<BASE_URL>/style.css` but you are expecting it to be at `<BASE_URL>/public/style.css` in your HTML file.
2. You configuration is is not correctly defined. i.e it should start with `micronaut` instead of `router`

Following configuration fixes the issue for you:

```
micronaut:
  router:
    static-resources:
      default:
        enabled: true
        mapping: "/public/**"
        paths: "classpath:public"
```

Answer (score 3):

The mapping `mapping: /**` will mount it under the root. If you want it available under `public` you probably want to add `/public` prefix to that mapping